# how can i use XML files in yii framework to read and write/read data in it

Tags: php, yii

how can i use XML files  in yii framework to read and write read  data in it from start to end
how can i use nosql also in yii

Answer (score 0):

i'm not found related class in yii framework, i use simplexml class usually.
 if you want use nosql , you can download extension, but i can't vouch for it .

this is for MongoDB :
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/